# Excel lookup between dates

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2013, vlookup

I have a spreadsheet that lists each client and the date when their status changed. e.g.

```
Client_Name   Transaction_Date    Status

ClientA       1/1/2017            Level_1

ClientB       2/1/2017            Level_2

ClientA       3/1/2017            Level_3
```

In the previous example ClientA has status Level_1 from 1/1/2017 through 2/28/2017 and status Level_3 onward. I want to construct a lookup that takes the Client Name and a date and returns the Status at that date. So the desired output would be:

```
Client_Name   Evaluation_Date    Status

ClientA       1/1/2016            NA/ERROR

ClientA       1/2/2017            Level_1

ClientA       3/2/2017            Level_3
```

VBA solutions are fine as well. Something without an array formula would be ideal since this would be run over a very large table but I realize that may not be possible.

Comment: Are the Transaction dates in the master table always in Ascending order?

Comment: They can be. I pull it using a query from another database so it's no big deal to sort them that way.

Answer (score 3):

Based on what I best understand your question, I suggest a solution based on the assumption that your Transaction Date (at least for the same Client) is in Ascending Order. If not Sort your Table first on Client Name and then on Transaction Date. Also leave at least one cell above your data as that Row number is referred in the solution. Try this solution and revert back if this works for you or not.

In this example the sample Table is in Cells B4:D12. Enter Client in E4 and Enter Date in F4.

Now in G4 put the following Formula and press CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER from within the formula bar to create and Array Function.

```
=IF(MAX(IF(1=IF(F4>=IF($B$4:$B$12=E4,$C$4:$C$12,2958352),1,0),ROW($C$4:$C$12)-ROW($C$3),0))=0,"Not Found",INDEX($D$4:$D$12,MAX(IF(1=IF(F4>=IF($B$4:$B$12=E4,$C$4:$C$12,2958352),1,0),ROW($C$4:$C$12)-ROW($C$3),0))))
```

As you enter Client Name and Date in E4 & F4, G4 shall show the relevant Level. If the date is before any of the start Level Date, then "Not Found" id displayed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Only solution i could come up with was with an array, although it may not directly be your prefered choice its still there as an option.

```
{=IFERROR(VLOOKUP("ClientA"&"1/1/2016",CHOOSE({1,2},A2:A12&B2:B12,C2:C12),2,0),"NA/ERROR")}
```

You would just need to change "ClientA"&"1/1/2016" to the cells you are looking up, `A2:A12` & `B2:B12` would represent the 2 columns you are looking up from i.e Client_Name & Evaluation_Date

And Finally `C2:C12` is the column form which you wish to return a value, in your case the status.

[image]